# Using MutationObserver correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to monitor updates to a page using MutationObserver. I've read through the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver & https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) but can't seem to get this right.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        console.log(mutation)
    })
})

var config = {childList: true}

observer.observe(document, config)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the DOM element instead

`observer.observe(document.body, config)`

Answer (score 1):

```
// observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);

    // include your code for reacting to each mutation here

  });    
});

// target node
var target = document.getElementById('my-id');

// configuration
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// start observer
observer.observe(target, config);

// stop observer -- use this when you want to stop observing
// observer.disconnect();
```